# heroku getting started "Deploy the App" but get app error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I am going through the "Getting Started with Ruby on Heroku" instructions.

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-ruby#deploy-the-app

Step by step. I'm at "Deploy the app". I have executed the `heroku ps:scale web=1` command. I have not made any changes to the standard default sample application.

But when I go to the app, it says `Application Error... check the logs`.

In the log, I see the following lines:

```
2015-01-24T07:55:37.733478+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command bundle exec puma -t 5:5 -P ${PORT:-3000} -e ${RACK_ENV:-development}
2015-01-24T07:55:40.024681+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/puma-2.9.1/lib/puma/cli.rb:294:in `parse_options': invalid option: -P (OptionPar
ser::InvalidOption)
```

It looks to me that the Heroku command for starting the web server is incorrect. From what I can see, the -P parameter should be in lowercase.

Is there some way to fix this command?

Comment: There are also docs on Unicorn web server in Heroku DevCenter that explain the concept of the `Procfile`. Have a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your app seems to be configured with puma server incorrectly. This may be an issue with your procfile as indicated by D-side. Your procfile should live inside the root of your app.

When you deploy to heroku, it will look at this file and issue the commands to deal some of the server configuration.

See here

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-ruby#define-a-procfile

When you find your procfile you'll be able to make any adjustments. They give the example.

`web: bundle exec puma -t 5:5 -p ${PORT:-3000} -e ${RACK_ENV:-development}`

Comment: YES!  I think the root of my problem is that I have the Bitnami stack and I was walking through the Heroku getting-started guides from within my Bitnami console.  I have resolved the problem by opening a "plain" Windows cmd prompt and running through the tutorial step by step.  My app now works.